# android, how to find an ImageView by its bitmap?

Tags: java, android

Say I have a loop that creates ImageViews and adds them to a layout

```
final LinearLayout linLayRow1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LLrow1);
    ...
try {
FileInputStream in1 = new FileInputStream(masterPath+shiftimage);
BufferedInputStream buf1 = new BufferedInputStream(in1);
Bitmap bMap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf1);
ivBtnSym.setImageBitmap(bMap1);
in1.close();
buf1.close();
} catch (Exception e) { }
    ...
linLayBtnInside.addView(ivBtnSym);
```

And now I'd need to change the bitmap of an ImageView that is, for example, masterPath+"/1.png" to masterPath+"/2.png" ... how would you do that?

Thanks! :)

Comment: you have a root View with imageViews inside? or an array of ImageViews ?

Comment: I have a linearlayout ( final LinearLayout linLayRow1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LLrow1); ) with the IVs inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the image names are unique

You could try to use tags:

```
final LinearLayout linLayRow1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LLrow1);
    ...
try {
FileInputStream in1 = new FileInputStream(masterPath+shiftimage);
BufferedInputStream buf1 = new BufferedInputStream(in1);
Bitmap bMap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf1);
ivBtnSym.setImageBitmap(bMap1);
ivBtnSym.setTag(masterPath+shiftimage);
in1.close();
buf1.close();
} catch (Exception e) { }
    ...
linLayBtnInside.addView(ivBtnSym);
```

Now when you want to retrieve the ImageView:

```
ImageView retrieved = (ImageView) linLayBtnInside.findViewByTag(query);
```